# Can I find a finite increasing filtration for every $V\in\mathfrak{O}$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $V\in{O}$, I want to proof there exists a finite increasing filtration by submodules 
$0=V_0\subset V_1\subset\cdots\subset V_n=V$ such that $V_{i+1}/V_i$ is a highest weight module.
Since $V\in {O}$ than there exists a finite number of elements $\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_s$ such that 
$$P(V)\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^s D(\lambda_i)$$
so if I set $V_1=U(\mathfrak{g}(A))v$, $v\in V_{\lambda_1}$ and than how can I do?

Comment: Can you explain your notation? what is $O$, $\lambda$'s, $P(V)$, $D(\lambda)$, $A$?

Comment: The category $O$ is defined as follows. Its objects are $\mathfrak{g}(A)$-modules $V$ which are $\mathfrak{h}$-diagonalizable with finite-dimensional weight spaces and such that there exists a finite numbe of elements $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ sucht that

Comment: $$ P(V)\subset\bigcup D(\lambda_i).$$

Comment: where $P(V)$ denote the set of weights of $V$. And $D(\lambda_i)=\{\mu\in\mathfrak{h}^*|\mu\le \lambda\}$